# How to solve Cannot set property '_eventListeners' of undefined error with jest/jsdom?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs, jsdom

I am replacing karma with jest and when I created all needed files and settings which you can see below. When I executed npm jest got an error:

```
Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Cannot set property '_eventListeners' of undefined
at Window.close (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:475:51)
```

I found a solution with editing node_modules/* files that don't make sense.
When I tried to switch testEnvironment to 'node' it's looked ok but I think that's not a good solution when it isn't node service project.

/jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    coverageReporters: [
        "html",
        "text",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
            tsConfig: "tsconfig.test.json",
            babelConfig: true
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "node",
        "d.ts",
        "scss"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/fileMock.js",
        "\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/styleMock.js",
        "^worker-loader!": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/workerLoaderMock.js",
        "^resize-observer-polyfill$": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/resizeObserverPolyfillMock.js",
        "applicationinsights-js": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/appInsightsMock.js"
    },
    reporters: [
        "default",
        "jest-junit"
    ],
    setupFiles: [
        "<rootDir>/test/mocks/setupJest.js"
    ],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "<rootDir>/test/mocks/matchMedia.js"
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|d.ts)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    testMatch: [
        "<rootDir>/test/**/*-test.tsx"
    ],
    timers: "fake"
};
```

/setupJest.js

```
global.Intl = require("intl");
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')
global.AppSettings = {
    AUTHORITY_URL: "https://auth.blah.com",
    INSTRUMENTATION_KEY: "APP_SETTINGS_KEY",
    REALTIME_URL_BASE: "https//:realtime.blah.com"
};
```

my-test.js

```
import { Tooltip } from "../../src/components/shared";
import { expect, React, shallow } from "../test-utils";

describe("Tooltip with empty properties", () => {
    const component = shallow(<Tooltip tooltipText="" />);

    it("should have no text", () => {
        expect(component.find("span.tooltip-text").text()).to.have.length(0);
    });

    it("should have 'tooltip-container' class", () => {
        expect(component.hasClass("tooltip-container")).to.be.true;
    });

    it("should have child with 'tooltip-text' class", () => {
        expect(component.childAt(0).hasClass("tooltip-text")).to.be.true;
    });
});

describe("Tooltip with set properties", () => {
    const expectedClass = "test-class";
    const expectedText = "Test tooltip text";
    const component = shallow(<Tooltip tooltipText={expectedText} className={expectedClass} />);

    it("should have the expected text", () => {
        expect(component.find("span.tooltip-text").text()).to.be.equal(expectedText);
    });

    it("should have the expected classes", () => {
        expect(component.hasClass("tooltip-container")).to.be.true;
        expect(component.hasClass(expectedClass)).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you put the content of the failing test and what is in your `setupJes.js`?

Comment: I have 17 tests and each test failed. setupJest.js:

 `global.Intl = require("intl");
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')
global.AppSettings = {
    AUTHORITY_URL: "https://auth.blah.com",
    INSTRUMENTATION_KEY: "APP_SETTINGS_KEY",
    REALTIME_URL_BASE: "https//:realtime.blah.com"
};
`

Comment: Your test is failing because you have something that is undefined. We can not know what it is without look at it.

Comment: I added test above the comment.